# Detect mouse movement ( arc / Rub the screen movement / infinity sign movement )

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-canvas, mouseevent, dom-events

I try to detect via Javascript, the specific movement of the mouse as well as Tablet.

movements are:

- Arc:
  Creating an arch from right to left

[image]

- Rub the screen movement

[image]

- Infinity sign movement

[image]

Do you have any leads? how can I do to detect these movements?

Comment: The Arc is easy: All your tracked "X-coordinate" points should decrease (or all increase if the Arc is left-to-right).  However, a sloppy rub will look a lot like an infinity.  I don't see a solution for rub vs infinity other than using something other than infinity--maybe a slash (X and Y both increase).

Comment: i've found this : http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/21/jquery-fancy-gestures/
but the operation is not quite accurate: s